# importとLinked Frameworks and Librariesの違い

Tags: swift

Swift3を使っています。

(1) swiftファイルにimportで定義するFramework
(2) Project のGeneralタブにある「Linked Frameworks and Libraries」
の違いを教えてください。

例えば、AVFoundationを(1)でimportすれば、(2)に指定しなくても使えたりします。
この用途の場合は、こう指定という形で教えていただければ理解しやすいので、ご存知の方ご教示お願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.swiftファイル内で`import`するのは、その.swiftファイル（クラス）の中でimportしたクラスのインスタンスにメッセージを送るためのインターフェースの参照のためです。
　なので、Frameworkか独自クラスかに関わりなく、XXX.swiftというXXXクラス内で別のクラスYYYのインスタンスをハンドリングするためには、YYYクラスの定義をインポートしなければなりません。

これに対して、Project Settingsの「Linked Frameworks and Libraries」は、フレームワークやライブラリーをプロジェクトが参照するか？の設定なので、意味するところが異なります。

まず、
(1) Appleが用意する多くのFrameworkを自分のプロジェクトで使う場合
(2) 他の方が作ったライブラリーやフレームワークを自分のプロジェクトで使う場合
の、２種類が考えられると思います

上の２種類は、そのフレームワークを自分のアプリケーションに内包してリリースするために、Project Settingsの「Build Phase」の
「Linked Binary With Libraries」に「このアプリはこのフレームワーク（やライブラリー）をリンクして下さい」と指定する必要があります。これは(1)であっても(2)であってもです。

「Copy Frameworks」に「このフレームワークは自前で他の人の環境には無いはずだから、アプリケーションの中にコピーしてね」と指定する必要があります。これは、(2)に対してのみで充分です。
　なぜ(1)は「Copy Frameworks」に記述する必要が無いか？は、OSが既にそのフレームワークを持ってくれているからです。

この様に、Project Settingsの「Build Phase」に指定した内容のダイジェスト（的なもの）が、Generalの「Embedded Binaries」と「Linked Frameworks And Libraries」です。
　なので、Generalで、参照するライブラリーやフレームワークを指定しても良いのですが、より細かな指定はBuild Phaseの方で行え、その結果はGeneralにも反映されるので、Generalの方を編集するより、Build Phaseの方を編集した方が良いと僕は思います。